# Creating a Lottery

Tags: java, user-input

Generate a lottery of a three digit number. The program prompts the user to enter a three-digit number and
determines whether the user wins according to the following rules:
(RULE 1). If the user input matches the lottery number in the exact order, the award is
$10,000.
(RULE 2). If all digits in the user input match all digits in the lottery number, the award is
$3,000.
(RULE 3). If one digit in the user input matches a digit in the lottery number, the award is
$1,000.

I need help getting my program to function as intended with all that is seen in the code. No arrays, no strings, nothing other than what is already there. My issue is that I cannot get a guess of 110 to ignore rule 2. I set it to 100 to test all the rules.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int lottery = 100;

 // Prompt the user to enter a guess
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your lottery pick (three digits): ");
        int guess = input.nextInt();

 // Get digits from lottery
        int lotteryDigit1 = lottery / 100;
        int lotteryDigit2 = (lottery % 100) / 10;
        int lotteryDigit3 = lottery % 10;

 // Get digits from guess
        int guessDigit1 = guess / 100;
        int guessDigit2 = (guess % 100) / 10;
        int guessDigit3 = guess % 10;

        System.out.println("The lottery number is " + lottery);

 // RULE1 Check the guess
        if (guess == lottery)
            System.out.println("Exact match: you win $10,000");
 // RULE2   
        else if ((guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit1
            || guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit2 
            || guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit3)
            && (guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1
            || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit2
            || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit3)
            && (guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit1
            || guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit2
            || guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit3))
            System.out.println("Match all digits: you win $3,000");
    // RULE3
        else if ((guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit1
            || guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit2
            || guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit3)
            || (guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1
            || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit2
            || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit3)
            || (guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit1
            || guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit2
            || guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit3))   
            System.out.println("Match one digit: you win $1,000");

        else
            System.out.println("Sorry, no match");
    }
 }
```

UPDATE:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class NewClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        int lottery = 456;

 // Prompt the user to enter a guess
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your lottery pick (three digits): ");
        int guess = input.nextInt();

 // Get digits from lottery
        int lotteryDigit1 = lottery / 100;
        int lotteryDigit2 = (lottery % 100) / 10;
        int lotteryDigit3 = lottery % 10;

 // Get digits from guess
        int guessDigit1 = guess / 100;
        int guessDigit2 = (guess % 100) / 10;
        int guessDigit3 = guess % 10;

        System.out.println("The lottery number is " + lottery);

  // Sum up both sets of digits to compare for 3 inconsecutive matches
        int guessSum = guessDigit1 + guessDigit2 + guessDigit3;
        int lotterySum = lotteryDigit1 + lotteryDigit2 + lotteryDigit3;

 // RULE1 Check the guess
        if (guess == lottery)
            System.out.println("Exact match: you win $10,000");
 // RULE2   
        else if ((guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit1
            || guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit2 
            || guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit3)
            && (guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1
            || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit2
            || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit3)
            && (guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit1
            || guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit2
            || guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit3)
            && guessSum == lotterySum)      
            System.out.println("Match all digits: you win $3,000");
// RULE3
        else if ((guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit1
            || guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit2
            || guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit3)
            || (guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1
            || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit2
            || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit3)
            || (guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit1
            || guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit2
            || guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit3))   
            System.out.println("Match one digit: you win $1,000");

        else
            System.out.println("Sorry, no match");
    }
 }
```

This seems to work above all else. I've been cycling through numbers to test against the guess. I've not encountered a wrong guess with this. `&& guessSum == lotterySum)` used only with RULE2.

Comment: The mixing of `&&` and `||` in the first `else if` could be causing problems. Try checking each digit in separate statement, or nest them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you're not accounting for repeat digits.  You could check to make sure all the digits add up to the sample number, ie:

```
1+1+0 = 2
1+0+0 = 1
1!=2
Move onto rule 3.
```

Using this code:

```
guessDigit1  + guessDigit2 + guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit1 + lotteryDigit2 + lotteryDigit3
```

I don't know if this will solve all of your problems, but it's  a start, and it should solve your immediate issue with the '110' value. Good luck!

Comment: Summing the digits will not work, this will introduce a number of collisions.  For instance, if the lottery is `456` the guess `178` would match rule 2.

Comment: I meant summing the digits in addition to the code that's already there, as an additional check for rule 2.  But it's admittedly probably not the most comprehensive solution.

Comment: It is simply wrong.  There is no way summing the digits will correctly match rule 2.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here that you have duplicates, so current condition for rule 2 evaluates to true for 100 <=> 110

to eliminate this effect the usual variant is to sort digits in both number and compare, like this (pseudo language):

```
if (sortDigits(lottery) == sortDigits(guess))
```

if you cannot use arrays, here is simple functions which sorts 3 digit numbers:

```
int sortDigits(int n) {
int d1 = n/100;
int d2 = (n/10)%10;
int d3 = n%10;

int min = Math.min(d1, Math.min(d2, d3));
int max = Math.max(d1, Math.max(d2, d3));
int mid = -1;
if (min == d1) mid = Math.min(d2, d3);
else if (min == d2) mid = Math.min(d1, d3);
else mid = Math.min(d1, d2);

return (min*100) + (mid*10) + max;
}
```

Comment: This type of coding... I've not seen yet.

Comment: @ChrisRedfieldea I'm not sure what you mean under "type of coding" here, it is just an idea how you can compare digits of 2 numbers to be the same sets without using arrays/sets/explicit sorting

Comment: I haven't seen Max/Min used yet. I'm not that far.

Comment: @ChrisRedfieldea it is very simple functions, you can implement them instead of using library ones if needed

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you check every digit of the guess with every digit of the lottery. This is the reason that you are getting the error, you need to remember what you have matched. 
A really quick and dirty solution in order to do that is to check for doubles and replace them with a value that will not ever be matched, like -1:

```
    if(guessDigit1 == guessDigit2){
        guessDigit1 = -1;
    }
    else if (guessDigit1 == guessDigit3 ) {
        guessDigit1 = -1;
    }
    else if (guessDigit2 == guessDigit3 ) {
        guessDigit2 = -1;
    }
```

Note that this is not the best solution at all!

UPDATE: In order to remember what you have checked you have to implement many if conditions. The pseudo code for one of them is the following:

```
If guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1 
    if guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit2 
        if guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit3
             -> You found all digits
    else if guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit3
        if guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit2
        -> You found all digits
```

Of course you have to implement this code * 3 because you need to create another 2 ifs for  guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit1 and guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit1 .

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional for Rule 2 is wrong; it's currently saying (in pseudo code):

```
IF  guessDigit1 is anyLotteryDigit
AND guessDigit2 is anyLotteryDigit
AND guessDigit3 is anyLotteryDigit
```

This clearly isn't what you're looking for, since it means multiple guess digits can match the same lottery digit, as you've run into with `110` matching `100` - since `1` and `0` are both in the winning number, it passes even though it shouldn't.

Instead, you want to match each digit to the *remaining* digits.  The "right" way to do this would be with a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), but it sounds like you can't use those yet.  You can do it manually, it's just a bit of work to write out all the cases.  Basically, you compare one digit of the guess to one digit of the lottery, then compare the remaining two guess digits *to the remaining two lottery digits*.  Rinse repeat for each digit.

Comment: ...and you've hit the nail on the head! --at least in a way I could understand it. I see that it was doing that but I thought it was required because I needed a match no matter what.

Comment: Never mind. I've lost the understanding of it. 1 == 1, 2 == 3, 3 == 2. I'm trying my best to visualize it.

Comment: Can you please clear this up or better explain this to me. I've been at this for hours and I still can't fix it.

Comment: @ChrisRedfieldea please update your question with more details, what you've tried, what problems you're running into, etc.  Fundamentally, you need to compare each digit against exactly one other digit, whereas your current solution compares against *any* digit.

Comment: I think I can't figure this out or I was never meant to. If there has to be some sort of "memory" to the statements to check all possibilities then the program will not be accepted. What I have above is all that I can use. `&&` and `||` and `if` statements

Comment: It sounds like you have additional requirements (a homework assignment?) beyond simply making this work, so it might be best to explain your mental roadblock to your instructor.  They can do a better job of explaining the concepts they want you to learn.  Alternatively, try doing it with extra "memory" or whatever else you need first, if that's easier.  It's better than nothing, and likely will even help you see a way to avoid the things you can't use.

Comment: All code is to be uploaded to a program with specific limitations. I was only able to work with what was presented. I think I figured it out because I've yet to see an "error" with the code in my updated response.

Answer (score 0):

As @dimo414 (and the other answers) have mentioned, you need some sort of memory for which digits you're checking against.  The following conditionals will give you the permutations you're looking for.  If `matched1`, `matched2`, or `matched3` are `-1` at the end, it's not a match.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int lottery = 100;

        // Prompt the user to enter a guess
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your lottery pick (three digits): ");
        int guess = input.nextInt();

        // Get digits from lottery
        int lotteryDigit1 = lottery / 100;
        int lotteryDigit2 = (lottery % 100) / 10;
        int lotteryDigit3 = lottery % 10;

        // Get digits from guess
        int guessDigit1 = guess / 100;
        int guessDigit2 = (guess % 100) / 10;
        int guessDigit3 = guess % 10;

        System.out.println("The lottery number is " + lottery);

        int matched1 = -1;
        int matched2 = -1;
        int matched3 = -1;

        // RULE1 Check the guess
        if (guess == lottery) {
            System.out.println("Exact match: you win $10,000");
        } 
        // RULE2   
        else {
            if (guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit1) {
                matched1 = 1;
                if (guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit2) {
                    matched2 = 2;
                    if (guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit3) {
                        matched3 = 3;
                    }
                } else if (guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit3) {
                    matched2 = 3;
                    if (guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit2) {
                        matched3 = 2;
                    }
                }
            } else if (guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit2) {
                matched1 = 2;
                if (guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1) {
                    matched2 = 1;
                    if (guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit3) {
                        matched3 = 3;
                    }
                } else if (guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit3) {
                    matched2 = 3;
                    if (guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit1) {
                        matched3 = 1;
                    }
                }
            } else if (guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit3) {
                matched1 = 3;
                if (guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1) {
                    matched2 = 1;
                    if (guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit2) {
                        matched3 = 2;
                    }
                } else if (guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit2) {
                    matched2 = 2;
                    if (guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit1) {
                        matched3 = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (matched1 != -1 && matched2 != -1 && matched3 != -1) {
                System.out.println("Match all digits: you win $3,000");
            } 
            // RULE3
            else if ((guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit1 || guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit2 || guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit3)
                    || (guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1 || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit2 || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit3)
                    || (guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit1 || guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit2 || guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit3)) {  
                    System.out.println("Match one digit: you win $1,000");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, no match");
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

This first checks if the first digit of your guess is the first digit of the lottery. If so, it saves matched1 (for the digit of your guess) with the value 1 (for the first digit in the lottery). Then it checks the second guessed digit compared to digits 2 and 3 of the lottery. We don't check the second digit of your guess with the first digit of the lottery again here because we already know the first guess matched the first lottery. If the first digit didn't match the first lottery number, then we see if the first digit of the guess is the second digit of the lottery number, and rinse and repeat.  (If that were the case, then matched1 would be 2 for the second digit of the lottery.)

All matching values of (matched1,matched2,matched3) are (1,2,3), (1,3,2), (2,1,3), (2,3,1), (3,1,2), and (3,2,1). You can see how all of these permutations are covered in the nested if statements above.

Comment: In your example of guessing `110` against lottery `100`, you'll end up with (`matched1`,`matched2`,`matched3`) as (1,-1,-1).

Answer (score 0):

i think i know this, its maybe because 110 is true in rule2 and also in rule3 thats why it displays the output of both rules. this is my boolean expression for rule2

```
((guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit2
            && guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit3
            && guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit1)
            || (guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit3
            && guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1
            && guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit2)
            || (guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit1
            && guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit3
            && guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit2)
            || (guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit3
            && guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit2
            && guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit1)
            || (guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit2
            && guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1
            && guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit3))
```

all possible answer is there.

Answer (score -2):

Instead, you want to match each digit to the remaining digits. The "right" way to do this would be with a Set, but it sounds like you can't use those yet. You can do it manually, it's just a bit of work to write out all the cases. Basically, you compare one digit of the guess to one digit of the lottery, then compare the remaining two guess digits to the remaining two lottery digits. Rinse repeat for each digit.

Would it be something like this:

```
else if ((guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit2 
            || guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit3)
            && (guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1
            || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit3)
            && (guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit1
            || guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit2))
            System.out.println("Match all digits: you win $3,000");
```

This is all I can work with--no other formulas. A program used to turn-in my code is very particular about the input. It'll only accept what it has been set to accept.

Comment: I don't care if I get marked down. I'm  trying my best to understand this. I  do  not  see   what  I  am  doing  wrong. I've gone through all the combinations I can understand...

Comment: Think about 567 and 765, you cant only check the different positions.

Comment: ...please expand on that.

Comment: My answer has all the conditional statements you need to figure out all permutations of the lottery number and your guess.

Comment: Why did you use the following formula to generate the lottery numbers:  int lotteryDigit1 = lottery / 100;
        int lotteryDigit2 = (lottery % 100) / 10;
        int lotteryDigit3 = lottery % 10;